# How can I reset powers in Multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to respec in multiplayer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53849/is-it-possible-to-respec-in-multiplayer)

In multiplayer there's a Reset Powers option on the Powers screen for any character, but it's greyed out. What allows me to use that option?

I know I can promote a character, but I don't want to start from level 1, just reset my powers and keep my level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, turns out there's a [gold rank, single use item](http://social.bioware.com/forum/Mass-Effect-3/Mass-Effect-3-Multiplayer-Discussion-/Ways-to-Reset-Powers-9289884-1.html) that lets you reset your powers/respec for multiplayer. Sounds like it only affects a single character too, so it's not nearly as easy to respec as I hoped.

You'd have to buy it from the store, in a Veteran's pack. It's a Rare item, andyou only have a *chance* pf getting it. I haven't got one yet to confirm though.