# How do i promote from multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3-multiplayer, mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does it mean to “promote a multiplayer character”?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53673/what-does-it-mean-to-promote-a-multiplayer-character)

In Mass effect 3 there is this achievment for promoting a multiplayer character, i have been trying for this since it came out( i always look at the achievments before i play any game), and im not quite sure as to what this mean's or even how im supposed to pull this off. can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

You level up a class to level 20 (max)  and then go to the "choose a character screen" and press promote.   It resets you to level 1.  Not sure what else it does...  It also puts your level 20 multiplayer in your story mode so you will have them by your side.