# What is the difference between "Total Military Strength" and "Effective Military Strength"?

Tags: mass-effect-3

As the title states, I'm utterly confused about these two ratings. The former is at 6712, while the latter is as 3356.

**Which of these numbers determines my ending?**

*Note: I've seen the answers giving the varying numbers, as well as the IGN link that states them, but I don't know what number they're actually referring to.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is simple as this:

The **Total Military Strength** is the numerical total of all of your **War assets**.

The **Effective Military Strength** is that total, multiplied by your **Galactic Readiness**.

Judging from your numbers, your **Galactic Readiness** is sitting at *50%*

The **Effective Military Strength** determines your ending.

Answer (score 4):

## Total*Readiness=Effective

**Total** Military Strength is the total sum of all War Resources you've acquired. This is *multiplied* by the Readiness Percentage from the **Galaxy at War** mechanic, which can be increased [by engaging in multiplayer, and playing the Mass Effect:Infiltrator iOS/Android game.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53690/what-are-all-the-ways-to-increase-readiness)

**Effective** Military Strength is what determines the ending. This means that if you enter the final mission with a **total** Military Strength of below 10,000, you can manipulate the ending via Galaxy at War to see a variety of endings. The exact amount of manipulation possible will vary based upon your total, but it seems that to see the broadest possible range of endings on one playthrough, you would want your total assets to be somewhere between 4,000 and 5,000 -  note that this does preclude the 'best' ending however.

Comment: Being unable to play either of those, there's no way to get my Galactic Readiness higher than 50%? Way to ruin it for me, BioWare. It doesn't seem possible to hit the 5000 mark through solo play.

Comment: You can easily hit the **10,000** mark through solo play if you're a completist.

Comment: Then I must still have a ways to go. I've completed asset collection from every galaxy, and done every side mission I've found. Hopefully a lot more become available after Thessia.

Comment: impossible a friend just finshed everything and his total assets were 6500