# What's this grey bar doing in my war assets?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Early on in the game, I took a look at my war asset screen, and didn't give it a passing thought. I've recently come back after doing a mission to see how many points it provided me with, and I noticed this:

[image: Mass Effect War Assets screen with freehand rectangular pointing device]

I figure the blue bar is the current asset amount, and the "minimum" line is fairly obvious. However, I don't quite understand what the gray bar (outlined by the orange rectangular thing) is for. Is it some form of a bonus meter? Maybe it's the potential amount of assets currently available to pick up by side quests?

What is this grey box doing in my war assets screen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The gray bar represents the total value your War Assets *would* be worth, if you had 100% Readiness Rating.

Without playing any of the multiplayer mode or the other tie-in games, your Readiness Rating will always be 50%.  The more multiplayer you play, the higher the Readiness Rating, and the less gray bar (and therefore the more blue bar) you'll have.

Being at 50% means that you'll have to find 2x the amount of War Assets to get the same ending as a person who has 100%.

This mechanic is also explained in this question:

[What is the difference between "Total Military Strength" and "Effective Military Strength"?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55131/what-is-the-difference-between-total-military-strength-and-effective-military)

Comment: Well, that's a bit disappointing... Thought I had a nice bar I could fill up and call all systems "complete". Ah, well. Thanks for this info though!

Answer (score 1):

They greyed out part of the bar shows how much military effectivness you lose due your galactic readiness. Since you have 50% readiness, 50% of your bar is grey, the full bar shows where you'd be with max readiness.