# What is the maximum possible N7 level?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Your N7 increases by leveling characters and promoting them. What is the maximum N7 level that can be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one.  It is simply the sum of the levels of all of your multiplayer characters, plus bonuses earned from "[promotion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53673/what-does-it-mean-to-promote-a-multiplayer-character)".

Comment: It is not just the sum, the N7 # increase when you promote a character

Answer (score 0):

The current highest N7 level (On PS3) is about 42,000 (As of August 21, 2013)

Answer (score -1):

I've seen a number of people on very neat N7 5000, and never anyone above this. Based on the size of the numbers in the box on the multi-player lobby, its unlikely it would go above 9999 without reformatting.

Comment: Should be simple enough to test - just promote 333 characters and get your 334th up to at least level 10.