# How to increase N7 number in ME3

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

What are the different ways to increasing your N7 number in ME3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum possible N7 level?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55962/what-is-the-maximum-possible-n7-level)

Comment: I don't think so, the other question only asked what the maximum number is, this one is asking for a method.

Comment: @SteveV I agree, that was my thinking when I posted both questions. I was trying hard to limit the question's scope.

Comment: Except that the questions were asked within minutes of each other, and the answer for the other question contains the answer to this one.  Not to mention that you clearly already knew the answer.  So I don't see the point in asking both questions.

Comment: @bwarner I knew two ways, and the promotion bonus is immediately evident. I was interested in an exhaustive answer, not guess work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Increasing any class level in multiplayer (+1 for every level), or a bonus from promoting a max level class (which gives +10 N7).

Answer (score 3):

By levelling your characters and promoting them at level 20.

Answer (score -3):

The best way is on firebase reactor. Wait until your team members are in the reactor, then press the button near the door. 
Magic will happen, and your N7 will increase dramatically. Also people will love you