# How much is a level 20 multiplayer character worth as a promoted war asset?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does it mean to “promote a multiplayer character”?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53673/what-does-it-mean-to-promote-a-multiplayer-character)

I'm thinking about promoting a level 20 character in exchange for single-player war assets, but before I do, I want to know if it's worth the cost.

**How much is a level 20 multiplayer character worth as a promoted war asset?**

Thanks.

Comment: the answer to your question is the [second answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/55624/3917) in the dupe question

Comment: np, your question is still useful and will refer people to the other question in the future

Comment: I'm not sure what to think of this question. Although that question does explain what it does, the question itself doesn't ask what the specific rewards do. Although a posted answer to that question gives the specific reward, someone looking for the answer to my question would not think to look there. As a general StackExchange example, is this worth standing alone?

Comment: feel free to ask this on meta to get a consensus on the answer

Comment: [Link in Meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4274/is-it-a-duplicate-if-someone-gave-a-correct-answer-in-a-different-question)